# How to display actions when long Press on React Native App Icon?

Tags: react-native

I am using `React Native`, in short what I want is to display actions when user long presses on app icon just like this below;

[image]

As you can see Scan Qr, Bundles, Discounts are showing after long press on app's icon?
How we can achieve this in react native?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an Android feature named [App Shortcuts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html). iOS not supported.

Try [react-native-app-shortcuts](https://github.com/lokyoung/react-native-app-shortcuts) package to achieve this.